# Prevent Anchor navigate if inner Button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button like the below

[image]

If a user clicks on the **phone number portion**, I'd like one action to be called.
If a user clicks on any other part of the rest of the Anchor, they should navigate to a different page.

I've nested everything into an anchor element like so

```
<a id = "contact_button_outer" href = "http://example.com/linkedtopage">
   <button id = "contact_button">
       Get Started Now. 
       <span id = "call_sales_button" onclick = "call();">
          Call 111-111-1111
       </span>
   </button>
</a>
```

The call function is defined as

```
function call(){
    /*what it do*/
    return false
}
```

I've also added z-indexes to both the anchor and the span, with the span having a higher index than the anchor.

If the user clicks on the phone number span, the default anchor action is still redirecting the browser to the linked page.

How would you prevent the default action from occurring in this instance?

Comment: Why not just remove, or unwrap, one of the links and use an `a` with a `tel://`  protocol to handle the calling natively (if supported)?

Comment: While your question is really clear and well formulated, why on earth would one want to do that (in the means of an intuitive User Interface?)

Comment: use external listener instead of onclick...and use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation)

Comment: @DavidThomas This is for an in browser calling system designed to work on non-mobile devices.  Specifically, I am using Twilio's API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Never use two or more nested Action Elements (`a > button` or vice-versa)
- Use [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default browser action of following a href if some condition is met
- Your condition should be *"if a clicked element triggers a function, but has an Anchor parent - preventDefault()!"*

```js
const fn = {
  call(evt) {
    // Check if there's an Anchor element as parent
    if (evt.target.closest("a")) evt.preventDefault(); // Do not follow parent link
    // Call instead!
    console.log("calling 111-111-1111")
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll("[data-click]").forEach(EL => {
  EL.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    const fnName = evt.currentTarget.dataset.click;   // "call"
    if (fn[fnName]) fn[fnName](evt);
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com/linkedtopage">
  Get Started Now. 
  <b data-click="call">Call 111-111-1111</b>
</a>
```

PS: Preferably don't do that, wrap into links only the portions you want to be links, and the other ones create click handlers for JS.

Additional read:

- [Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: why does preventDefault work here? it should only prevent the default action on the internal span, but the event would still be propagated to the anchor and it's default action should still be fired ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 edited to make more sense.

Comment: thanks, but I still don't get why stop propagation on child would not stop the default behaviour on the parent, and why prevent default on child prevents the default behaviour on the parent. i would expect that stopping propagation on the child would stop every default + added event handler on the parent as well, as the parent would not recieve the event now

Answer (score -1):

`return false` inside *call()* will prevent default browser behaviour on span, but the event will still bubble to parent elements and actions on them is not cancelled. What you need to do is prevent the event from propagating to parent elements. You do this by doing something like this below

```
function call(event) {
    event.stopPropagation(); // modern browsers (IE9 and above)
    event.cancelBubble = true; // IE8

    //do something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if nothing work, try

```
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```